# FixedLength giving issues while trying to fetch only a subset of values

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I do have a file which have many records or columns in a single row. This file is being used across multiple systems. Hence not all fields are required for my requirement. Hence if i set only a subset of values as shown below

```
<property name="lineTokenizer">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
        <property name="names" value="aa,cc,vv,bb" />
        <property name="columns" value="1-578,579-579,580-580,581-581" />
    </bean>
</property>
```

I get an exception as below

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectLineLengthException: Line is shorter than max range 581
org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer.doTokenize(FixedLengthTokenizer.java:109)
org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.AbstractLineTokenizer.tokenize(AbstractLineTokenizer.java:112)
org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper.mapLine(DefaultLineMapper.java:43)
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:180)
```

Do we have to do anything special to fetch only subset of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is saying that the line is *shorter* than the range you're providing.  As in, you're mapping too many columns, not too few.

That being said, you need to map the entire record in the `FixedLengthTokenizer`.  However, the `FieldSetMapper` you use doesn't need to use all those fields.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exception when the final field was actually not a fixed length, but rather, shorter than expected.  All other fields were the expected length, but the final needed to allow for fewer characters.

I was able to adjust the final parameter to not include the final value like this:

```
<property name="lineTokenizer">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
        <property name="names" value="aa,cc,vv,bb" />
        <property name="columns" value="1-578,579-579,580-580,581" />
    </bean>
</property>
```

Per Spring documentation:

> If the last range is open then the rest of the line is read into that column (irrespective of the strict flag setting)

In the case of the OP the final field was only 1 character, so this solution makes less sense, however, with a larger range it could result in the same error message even when the names values match the columns values provided.

Source:
[Fixed Length Tokenizer Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/FixedLengthTokenizer.html#setColumns-org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.Range...-)